# Set 2nd line of text to tab like 1st

Tags: html

I am trying to format some `HTML` and write it (by hand in Notepad++) which is no easy feat for me.  I have my syntax close to what it needs to be, but when the text (mainly the AAAA line) carries over to a secondary line it looses the `padding` that was added.  Also, I think it is the `<p>` div tag that is causing it to add a space between the header and the sub-data.   This is my `HTML` and attached is a screenshot of what I want it to look like.

```
<p>This would be acceptable:<br>
<p style="text-indent: 5em;"><strong>Bookbag</strong></p>
<p style="text-indent: 5em;">Fill it full of your favorite items!</p>
<p style="text-indent: 5em;"><strong>Extra Clothes</strong></p>
<p style="text-indent: 5em;">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</p>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `padding` rather than `text-indent` on a wrapping block element.

```
<p>This would be acceptable:<br>
<div style="padding-left:15px;">
<p><strong>Bookbag</strong></p>
<p>Fill it full of your favorite items!</p>
<p><strong>Extra Clothes</strong></p>
<p>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/at4Lotno/

Answer (score 0):

`text-indent` add space only before first line of text, `padding` will add space before whole content

```html
<p>This would be acceptable:<br>
<p style="text-indent: 5em;"><strong>Bookbag</strong></p>
<p style="text-indent: 5em;">Fill it full of your favorite items!</p>
<p style="text-indent: 5em;"><strong>Extra Clothes</strong></p>
<p style="padding-left: 5em;">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</p>
```